# aggregate time series data faster

Tags: r, data.table

I need to calculate some features by distributing them over time and then aggregating as shown below.  The code produces the right results but I have roughly 1 million rows of data in my actual set and run time with a code similar to below takes several days of my machine.  I'm looking for a more efficient code.  I'm not sure with `xts` or `tidyverse` packages would be useful here for a speedup.  I worked with `data.table` thinking It would help with speed - maybe it's the wrong choice. Any ideas?

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

#toy example
rows=1000
set.seed(1)
data=data.table(
  customer.arv = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00")+dminutes(sample(1:(60*24*7),rows,replace = T)),
  location = sample(1:4,rows,replace = T),
  customer.type = sample(LETTERS[1:5],rows,replace = T),
  charge = sample(seq(50,200,10),rows,replace = T)
  )
data[,':='(customer.dep = customer.arv+dminutes(sample(1:500,rows,replace = T)),
           arv.time.floor = floor_date(customer.arv,"hours"),
           arv.hour = hour(customer.arv))]

#distribute the charge over the length of stay (departure-arrival) and calculate the hourly charge
tot.hourly.charge = function(pass.location,pass.arv.time.floor,pass.customer.type) {
  full.hr.cust = data[customer.arv<=pass.arv.time.floor&customer.dep>=pass.arv.time.floor+dhours(1)&location==pass.location&customer.type==pass.customer.type,sum(charge)]
  partial.hr.cust = data[customer.arv<=pass.arv.time.floor&customer.dep<pass.arv.time.floor+dhours(1)&customer.dep>pass.arv.time.floor&location==pass.location&customer.type==pass.customer.type,sum(charge*minute(customer.dep)/60)]
  return(full.hr.cust+partial.hr.cust)
}

#aggregate
res = data[,.(hourly.charge = tot.hourly.charge(location,arv.time.floor,customer.type)), by=.(location,arv.time.floor,customer.type)]

#sample output
res[order(location,customer.type,arv.time.floor)][1:10,]
    location      arv.time.floor customer.type hourly.charge
 1:        1 2020-01-01 00:00:00             A       0.00000
 2:        1 2020-01-01 03:00:00             A     190.00000
 3:        1 2020-01-01 06:00:00             A     216.66667
 4:        1 2020-01-01 09:00:00             A     100.00000
 5:        1 2020-01-01 12:00:00             A     100.00000
 6:        1 2020-01-01 14:00:00             A      16.66667
 7:        1 2020-01-01 15:00:00             A      50.00000
 8:        1 2020-01-01 18:00:00             A      62.50000
 9:        1 2020-01-01 20:00:00             A       0.00000
10:        1 2020-01-01 22:00:00             A     190.00000
```

Comment: could you explain more in detail on a simple example what the aggregation is supposed to do?

Comment: for example, for arv.time.floor "2020-01-01 03:00",location==1,type==A:  add up charges for all customers who arived prior to 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 03:00 and after 2020-01-01 04:00.  for customers who arrived prior to 2020-01-01 03:00 and departed between 03:00 and 04:00, multiply their charge with the fraction of the hour they spent in the business between 03:00 and 04:00.  so, if a certain customer spent $300 and after at 03:20 (20 mins) their contribution to the hourly charge is $300*20/60=$100

Comment: have you Rprof'd `data[,.(hourly.charge`? I tried `replicate(n = 100, data[,.(hourly.charge,`, should point towards problems, `[`, `tot.hourly.charge`, but you know your problem better.

Comment: can you kindly share `data[, .N, .(location, arv.time.floor, customer.type)][, unique(N)]` for your actual dataset? And also `data[, range(arv.time.floor)]`

Comment: for the first: `[1]  1  5  4  2  3  8  6  7 10  9 12 13 11 15 14 16 18 17`.  for the date range: `[1] "2016-01-22 22:00:00 CST" "2020-06-30 23:00:00 CDT"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that you can try first:

```
data[, arv.time.floor.1h := arv.time.floor + 60*60]

full <- data[data, on=.(location=location, customer.type=customer.type, 
    customer.arv<=arv.time.floor, customer.dep>=arv.time.floor.1h),
    .(charge=x.charge, location, arv.time.floor=i.arv.time.floor, customer.type=i.customer.type)][,
        .(full.hr.cust=sum(charge)), keyby=.(location, customer.type, arv.time.floor)][
            is.na(full.hr.cust), full.hr.cust := 0]

partial <- data[data, on=.(location=location, customer.type=customer.type, 
    customer.arv<=arv.time.floor, customer.dep>arv.time.floor, customer.dep<arv.time.floor.1h),
    .(charge=x.charge, m=minute(x.customer.dep), location, arv.time.floor=i.arv.time.floor, customer.type=i.customer.type)][,
        .(partial.hr.cust=sum(charge * m / 60)), keyby=.(location, customer.type, arv.time.floor)][
            is.na(partial.hr.cust), partial.hr.cust := 0]

ans <- full[partial][, charge := full.hr.cust + partial.hr.cust]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)

#toy example
rows=1000
set.seed(1)
data=data.table(
    customer.arv = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00") + 60 * (sample(1:(60*24*7), rows, replace = TRUE)),
    location = sample(1:4,rows,replace = TRUE),
    customer.type = sample(LETTERS[1:5],rows,replace = TRUE),
    charge = sample(seq(50,200,10),rows,replace = TRUE)
)
data[, `:=`(customer.dep = customer.arv + 60 * sample(1:500,rows,replace = TRUE),
    arv.time.floor = as.POSIXct(round.POSIXt(customer.arv, units="hours")))]
setorder(data, location, customer.type, arv.time.floor)
```